# Display Visual Studio Find In Files results in alphabetical order

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, findinfiles

In Visual Studio 2015, I did a Find in Files search over a solution and noticed that the order of the results was not as I expected.

```
E:\Source Code\Manager\Manager.BusinessLogic\Permission\AppModuleManager.cs(158):                EnumPair<PermissionType> actualPermission = permissionValue as EnumPair<PermissionType>;
E:\Source Code\BusinessLogic\ValueObjects\EnumPair.cs(9):    public class EnumPair<T> : ObservableObject
E:\Source Code\BusinessLogic\ValueObjects\InheritedPermissionModel.cs(485):     public EnumPair<PermissionType> ViewPickups { get; set; }
E:\Source Code\Reports\Reports\Common\Model\EnumPair.cs(3):    public class EnumPair
E:\Source Code\BusinessLogic\InheritanceLogic\PermissionInheritanceManager.cs(148):                    resolvedKeywordPermissionItem.AllowKeyword = new EnumPair<PermissionType>(keywordPermission.AllowKeyword, source.GetType().Name);
```

I thought I would see the entries in "Source Code\BusinessLogic" first, the entry in "Source code\Manager" second, and the entry in "Source Code\Reports" last.  The order I see makes no sense.

I looked in the registry and found "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Find" as a possible location for a setting that would determine the display order.  Is there a setting, either in the registry or somewhere else, that I can change to make the Find results appear in alphabetical order?